# Select multiple rows' ids and use them for the WHERE IN clause in an update query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Already tried various solutions to solve my problem to select the IDs (from multiple rows), which are then used to update specific rows that match these IDs.

I have currently deployed the following. First the simple SELECT query for the IDs, which are then used for the WHERE clause in the next UPDATE query:

```
$SelectTSubjectsQuery = "
SELECT subject_id FROM teachers_subjects
WHERE teacher_id = :teacher_id";

$statement = $pdo->prepare($SelectTSubjectsQuery);
$statement->bindParam(':teacher_id', $_SESSION['teacher_id']);
$statement->execute();

$FetchedTSubjects = Array();
$FetchedTSubjects = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Now the UPDATE query, which should update the teacher_id and status_id in the table for the corresponding rows that match the request id and the afore selected subject_IDs:

```
$StatusUpdateQuery = "UPDATE requests_subjects SET teacher_id = :teacher_id, status_id = '2' WHERE request_id = :request_id AND requests_subjects.subject_id IN (".implode(',', $FetchedTSubjects).")";

$statement = $pdo->prepare($StatusUpdateQuery);
$statement->bindParam(':request_id', $_GET['id']);
$statement->bindParam(':teacher_id', $_SESSION['teacher_id']);
$statement->execute();
```

My requests_subjects table, which should be updated, looks like:

```
+---+-------------+------------+----------------+------------+
|id | request_id  | subject_id |   teacher_id   |  status_id |
+---+-------------+------------+----------------+------------+
| 1 |     19      |      1     |       0        |      1     |
| 2 |     19      |      2     |       0        |      1     |
| 2 |     19      |      3     |       0        |      1     |
| 2 |     20      |      1     |       4        |      3     |
| 2 |     21      |      1     |       5        |      3     |
+---+-------------+------------+----------------+------------+
```

So, e.g. if the teacher with the teacher_id = '2' with the subject_ids '2' and '3' opts for the request with the request_id = '19' then the rows with request_id = '19' and subject_ids '2' and '3' should be updated with the teacher_id '2' and the status_id = '2'.

edit: oh and of course the error I currently get (obviously it doesn't work with the Array in current WHERE clause):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'' in /var/www/xxx/html/teacher.php:227 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/xxx/html/teacher.php(227): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/xxx/html/teacher.php on line 227
```

I am thankful for every advice.

Comment: did you tried to execute this query separately in a mysql client?

Comment: I guess the problem is the `(".implode(',', $FetchedTSubjects).")` part which I can't test in the mysql client (I tested it with just (2,3) in the array, that works, but I don't know how to handle the afore selected array (with or without implode?) in the where clause of the update query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem, is that you need to put the data right in the array correctly...

```
$SelectTSubjectsQuery = "SELECT subject_id FROM teachers_subjects WHERE teacher_id = :teacher_id";

$statement = $pdo->prepare($SelectTSubjectsQuery);
$statement->bindParam(':teacher_id', $_SESSION['teacher_id']);
$statement->execute();

$FetchedTSubjects = Array();
$FetchedTSubjects = $statement->fetchAll()
```

From your code if you `print_r($FetchedTSubjects)` will get the following result or similar:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [subject_id] => 1
            [0] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [subject_id] => 2
            [0] => 2
        )
)
```

if you try to `implode(',',$FetchedTSubjects)` you actually are trying to convert an **array** to string so that is the meaning of

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause''
```

You need to do the following:

```
$SelectTSubjectsQuery = "SELECT subject_id FROM teachers_subjects WHERE teacher_id = :teacher_id";

$statement = $pdo->prepare($SelectTSubjectsQuery);
$statement->bindParam(':teacher_id', $_SESSION['teacher_id']);
$statement->execute();

$FetchedTSubjects = Array();

// iterate all the rows to get the subject_id of each and put in an independent array
foreach($statement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $subject) {
    array_push($FetchedTSubjects,$subject['subject_id']);
}
```

now if you `print_r($FetchedTSubjects)` you will get the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

You now you can successfully use `implode(',', $FetchedTSubjects)` that will return (1,2) as you expect it to do so

NOTE: `\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` is parameter for `PDOStatement::fetchAll` and `PDOStatement::fetch` [check it out!](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

> PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: returns an array indexed by column name as returned in your result set

Comment: Wonderful, it worked! Thanks and thanks for the comprehensive explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need to specify the table name here

```
requests_subjects.subject_id IN
```

Just change it to

```
subject_id IN
```

and give it a try.

Comment: Hi John, yes that's right, thanks. But it doesn't change anything concerning the error with the array in the where clause.